# Referencing .jar files in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, automated-tests, fest

I am trying to use FEST automation software. I am currently dealing with NetBeans 6.8 because it is what I have to use at work and am unable to upgrade the software at this time because of our system requirements

[TLDR: don't tell me to upgrade NetBeans because I can't]

I have downloaded the jar files from the google code repository and am trying to get a very simple application to work. I have tried adding the jar files to Libraries through the property panel for my project. NetBeans still cannot find these methods. Where else/how do I add these jar files to the class paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use .jar files in NetBeans, you can either add the jar file to your global libraries or your local libraries. It sounds like you tried doing it locally without much success. I recommend adding a library such that you can just pick from your list of libraries without needing to reload it. I use NetBeans 8.1 so it may be just a bit different for 6.8.

What you need to do is go to Tools->Library

Then you need to click on New Library at the bottom left of the dialogue box.

[AddLibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbDdD.png)

Name it and hit 'Ok'. Then, you'll add a new jar file by specifying your jar path. Hit 'Ok' again to save everything.

In order to use your new library, you'll need to then click on your Libraries folder in your project and add a new library. Select from the list of libraries the library you just created.

[SelectLibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYlMF.png)

Finally, you import your individual files in your library using the #import keyword as per usual. If you want to import everything, you'd type something akin to

```
import MyNewLibrary.*;
```

To load a library the way you tried to do it, you'd right click the libraries folder and click "Add JAR/folder" instead of "Add Library". Then you'd import everything.

If you still for some reason cannot get your library to work, then you probably aren't importing using the right name. Or, you might be trying to load a static library without using the static keyword.

Comment: Thank you! To anyone trying to use FEST specifically, you also have to "Frankenstein" a bunch of different jar files from across the web.